# Strange struct definition from crate nix

Tags: struct, rust

I just encountered this weird struct definition, it is in [fcntl.rs](https://github.com/nix-rust/nix/blob/3ca28f681ca7b7caa08809f19ae4f3eccc1d41a2/src/fcntl.rs#L51) from the crate [nix](https://crates.io/crates/nix).

```rust
pub struct OFlag: c_int {
    /// Mask for the access mode of the file.
    O_ACCMODE; 

    // other fields are omitted.
}
```

A normal struct in my perspective will be something like this:

```rust
struct Person{
    name: String,
    age: u8,
}
```

So, here are my doubts:

1. what is `OFlag: c_int`?

   > `c_int` is an type alias of i32. `pub type c_int = i32;`
2. Why don't its fields have any type annotation?

My surmise is that `OFlag` is of type `c_int`, and the fields are something similar to `enum`'s fields.(compliant to the open syscall function signature `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode)` ) But this is just my guesswork, an explanation citing rust official doc would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you quoted is not valid Rust code on its own. It's code that gets passed to an internal macro of the `nix` crate called `libc_bitflags!()`. This macro takes the quoted code as input and transforms it into valid Rust code.

The `libc_bitflags!()` macro is a [simple wrapper](https://github.com/nix-rust/nix/blob/3ca28f681ca7b7caa08809f19ae4f3eccc1d41a2/src/macros.rs#L55-L75) around the `bitflags!()` macro from the [bitflags crate](https://docs.rs/bitflags/latest/bitflags/index.html). The wrapper simplifies creating bitflags structs that take all their values from constants defined in the `libc` crate. For example this invocation

```
libc_bitflags!{
    pub struct ProtFlags: libc::c_int {
        PROT_NONE;
        PROT_READ;
        PROT_WRITE;
        PROT_EXEC;
    }
}
```

gets expanded to

```
bitflags!{
    pub struct ProtFlags: libc::c_int {
        const PROT_NONE = libc::PROT_NONE;
        const PROT_READ = libc::PROT_READ;
        const PROT_WRITE = libc::PROT_WRITE;
        const PROT_EXEC = libc::PROT_EXEC;
    }
}
```

which in turn will be expanded to Rust code by the `bitflags!()` macro. The `libc::c_int` type is used as the type of the `bits` field of the resulting struct. The constants inside will become associated constants of the resulting struct. See the documentation of the bitflags crate for further details.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the file you can see that the code inside the macro `libc_bitflags!`. The definition of the macro is [here](https://github.com/nix-rust/nix/blob/1dcc582f8eba50f6233bc0bf398ada4032469c1f/src/macros.rs#L55). There you can see that the macro `::bitflags::bitflags!` is called and that `libc_bitflags` almost redirects the full input to `bitflags`. You can read more about that crate [here](https://docs.rs/bitflags/latest/bitflags/index.html).

Now to your questions:

- `OFlag` will be after macro expansion a struct with a single attribute which is of type `c_int`:

```rust
pub struct OFlag {
    bits: c_int,
}
```

- The fields don't need a type because they won't exist anymore in the expanded code (after the macro was run). The bits are of the "type of the struct" so in your case `c_int`. The fields will be converted to associated constants:

```
impl OFlag {
    pub const O_ACCMODE = Self { bits: libc::O_ACCMODE };
}
```

You can create an expansion of an example in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7ba61a2084dd12ea40a3f8ed3dcf6546) (`Tools` -> `Expand macros`)